# Multiple read/write server-clinet

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a simple check of password&user name and then check on the tables, but I've a problem.

The client can read the first `println`('Enter user name'), but never gets to the second one('Enter password').

How can I implement this that the client can read and write multiple times?

```
        //write
        pr.println("Enter user name");
        pr.flush();
        //read
        String userNameRes = bf.readLine();
        //write
        pr.println("Enter password:");
        //read
        String password = bf.readLine();
```

And this at my clinet side:

```
//read
        String serverPasswordRes = bf.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverPasswordRes);

        //input write
        String userNameRes = in1.readLine();
        pr.println(userNameRes);
        pr.flush();

        //read
        String PasswordRes = bf.readLine();
        System.out.println(PasswordRes);

        //input write
        String passwordClinetRes = in1.readLine();
        pr.println(passwordClinetRes);
        pr.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put

```
    pr.println("Enter password:");
    pr.flush(); //add this
```

[flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush())

> Flushes the stream. If the stream has saved any characters from the various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their intended destination. Then, if that destination is another character or byte stream, flush it. Thus one flush() invocation will flush all the buffers in a chain of Writers and OutputStreams.